# KnockoutJS: Commented foreach with "afterAdd"

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

### The goal

Make this possible:

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: products, afterAdd: highlightIt } -->
<li>
   [...]
</li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

### The problem

The syntax is wrong. It seems to be possible only with `data-bind` attribute, like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: products, afterAdd: highlightIt">
    <li>
        [...]
    </li>
</ul>
```

### What is happening, eventually?

Nothing. Console displays no errors, but Knockout cannot work with the foreach because its do not know that comment is a foreach.

Someone have any idea?

Comment: What is not working? Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: @Nemesv Take a look at the main topic now.

Comment: Have you checked that the comments are rendered in the HTML. Because some web servers and browser are strip out the comments... because your code should work: http://jsfiddle.net/CZ5QN/